# compare working differently with generics involved

Tags: generics, f#, comparison

I stumbled upon some "odd behaviour". I was using the F# interactive to test some code and wrote

```
Seq.zip "ACT" "GGA" |> Seq.map ((<||) compare)
// val it : seq<int> = seq [-1; -1; 1]
```

Then I wanted to make a function out of it and wrote

```
let compute xs ys = Seq.zip xs ys |> Seq.map ((<||) compare)
// val compute : xs:seq<'a> -> xs:seq<'a> -> seq<int> when 'a : comparison
```

That generalized the first snippet of code and I thought that was a good thing... until I tried to use it

```
compute "ACT" "GGA"
// val it : seq<int> = seq [-6; -4; 19]
```

So somehow `compare` acts differently for the "same thing" when there is a different "point of view" (explicit type vs generics)

I know how to solve it: either by making the type explicit

```
let compute (xs: #seq<char>) // ... or char seq or string
```

Or keeping the type generic and composing with the `sign` function

```
let compute (* ... *) ((<||) compare >> sign)
```

**tl;dr the question is where does the difference in behavior come from exactly?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an intricate interplay between F# compiler optimization and .NET standard library optimization.

First, F# tries hard to optimize your program. When the types are known at compile time, and the types are primitive, and comparable, then the call to `compare` gets compiled to just straight up comparison. So comparing the characters in your example would look like `if 'A' < 'G' then -1 elif 'A' > 'G' then 1 else 0`.

But when you wrap the thing in a generic method, you take away the type information. The types are generic now, the compiler doesn't know that they are `char`. So the compiler is forced to fall back to calling `HashCompare.GenericComparisonIntrinsic`, which in turn calls `IComparable.CompareTo` on the arguments.

And now guess how `IComparable` is implemented on the `char` type? It simply subtracts the values and returns the result. Seriously, try this in C#:

```
Console.WriteLine( 'A'.CompareTo('G') ); // prints -6
```

Note that such implementation of `IComparable` is not technically a bug. According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43hc6wht(v=vs.110).aspx), it doesn't have to return only `[-1,0,+1]`, it can return any value so long as its sign is correct. My best guess would be that this is also done for optimization.

F# [documentation for `compare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.compare%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) doesn't specify this at all. It just says "result of the comparison" - go figure what that's supposed to be :-)

---

If you want your `compute` function to return only `[-1,0,+1]`, that can be easily achieved by making the function `inline`:

```
let inline compute xs ys = Seq.zip xs ys |> Seq.map ((<||) compare)
```

Now it will get expanded at call site, where the types are known, and the optimized code can be inserted. Keep in mind though that, since `[-1,0,+1]` behavior is not guaranteed in the docs, it may disappear in the future. So I would rather not rely on it.

Comment: Great answer.  As an aside, if the C# impl is an optimization, and the F# impl could simply reuse it, does that mean the F# one is *actively* inferior?

Comment: Nice answer ; I had lookep up about how `System.Char` had implemented IComparable so I knew about subtracting values. The information I didn't know was mostly the first part (about how F# optimize things away). I think I will stick with the added call to `sign` ; at least that is a defined behaviour (for no perceptible cost)

Comment: @DaxFohl I think I would have to agree that F# is actively inferior. But maybe not. It is definitely shorter to subtract than to jump around with conditional branching, but then the subtraction also comes with a function call (`CompareTo`). So I'd say it's a toss up. An experiment is required.

Comment: BTW, one of the reasons why it's more efficient to subtract than to branch is because with subtraction, you cannot ever suffer a [branch prediction failure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/2314532). Note that the answer I just linked to is probably **the** best answer on all of Stack Overflow! If you haven't seen it before, *definitely* read it. And even if you have seen it before, read it again for the sheer joy of seeing a question answered *so well*.